# PDF generation from XHTML in a LAMP environment

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-generation

Can anyone recommend a good server-side PDF generation tool that would work in a Linux environment. I want easy as possible, pass it a XHTML file (with images) and have it generate a PDF from the **rendered** source.

I don't have a massive budget, but anything under $1000 should be alright.

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [HTMLDoc](http://www.easysw.com/htmldoc/) about 8 years ago and it did a good job of turning HTML tables with some basic formatting into a decent PDF report. There also seems to be an [open source version](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I sounds like [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) might be of help...

Also, the creation of PDF documents is called "PDF printing". I believe that might help you find other resources.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at FOP, which stands for Formatting Objects Processor. It can generate PDF files on linux since it is Java based. From their site:

> Apache FOP (Formatting Objects Processor) is a print formatter driven
>   by XSL formatting objects (XSL-FO) and an output independent formatter. 
>   It is a Java application that reads a formatting object (FO) tree
>   and renders the resulting pages to a specified output. Output formats 
>   currently supported include PDF, PS, PCL, AFP, XML (area tree 
>   representation), Print, AWT and PNG, and to a lesser extent, RTF and 
>   TXT. The primary output target is PDF.

You can find it [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)

Answer (score 0):

I did some searching, what about [tbookdtd](http://tbookdtd.sourceforge.net/)?
It's downloadable [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=48834) but it hasn't been active since 2005.  It appears to convert the xml to Latex, into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated PHP's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdf.php)? There's also PHP [FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.freepdf) with a few different links. PHP primarily supports [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently came across [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/) which I have used to convert pages created in HTML into PDF documents. It uses PHP5 (assuming using PHP does not bother you). This is also assuming that you don't want to statically create HTML files on the file system and then convert them using some kind of command-line tool?

One problem I found with dompdf is that you don't get a whole lot of configuration options natively, but it is open-source and doesn't seem to be too large, so you could probably jury-rig something up pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have a budget take a look at the following [OpenEdge](http://www.openedgesoft.com/). I know that they did excatly what you want for us. A linux based PDF generation system.
I'd ask what they can do for you. Val Cassidy is the persons name.

BTW: I'm not getting anything for this and I don't even work for bespoke company anymore nor for OpenEdge ...

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at using OpenOffice via the [OpenOffice API](http://api.openoffice.org/) to load your XHTML document and export a PDF version. There is a bit of a learning curve to using the OpenOffice API but it is very powerful and can be run in server mode on systems without any graphical interface. It performs well - we've used it on some internal projects.